# Prove: $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{x+y+z}\implies \frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{1}{y^5}+\frac{1}{z^5}=\frac{1}{(x+y+z)^5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Prove that for all real numbers $x,y,z$:
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{x+y+z}\implies \frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{1}{y^5}+\frac{1}{z^5}=\frac{1}{(x+y+z)^5}.$$

Comment: are $x,y,z$ positive reals?

Comment: i would think we can use $AM-GM$ if the variables are positive

Answer (score 1):

The condition gives
$$(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)=xyz$$ or
$$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)=0$$
and since for $y=-x$ it's true and we need to prove something symmetry, we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We have
$$
0=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{x+y+z}=\frac{(x + y)(x + z)(y + z)}{(y + z + x)xyz}.
$$
Hence we have 
$$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)=0.$$